# Can't create a bot with Tweepy in Python. Traceback (most recent call last) Error appears

Tags: python, twitter, bots, tweepy, traceback

I wanted to create a twitter bot just to test things out.

I wrote this code:

```
auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(api_key, api_key_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)

api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

api.create_friendship("******")
```

(Obviously I also created variables like api_key = "...")

But the only message I get out of the console ist:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\PycharmProjects\TwitterBot\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    api.create_friendship("******")
  File "C:\Users\Anwender\PycharmProjects\TwitterBot\venv\lib\site-packages\tweepy\api.py", line 46, in wrapper
    return method(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: API.create_friendship() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Can someone tell me whats wrong?
Tweepy is installed. Had a few problems until i installed in in PyCharm itself instead of cmd.

When I first installed tweepy I upgraded pip to the latest version.
Don't know if this is the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

It's likely due to the lack of keyword arguments in `create_friendship()`.

You'll need to identify whichever argument you're passing. For example, if "*****" is the user id, then:

`api.create_friendship(user_id = "******")`